# input three numbers and arrange them in descending order using nested if

Tags: java, netbeans, bluej

I could only come up with this much. Please be patient and help me, I'm only 14 years old!!
The program has to be done using nested ifs only.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P2
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter three number");
       int n1=sc.nextInt();
       int n2=sc.nextInt();
       int n3=sc.nextInt();
       int max=0,min=0;
       if(n1>n2)
       {
           if(n1>n3)
           {max=n1;}
           if(n3>n1)
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: try writing this out on a piece of paper first.  Also when you get to the last choice consider using `else`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i could come up with this much only. i'm still a beginner.

Comment: Nested `if` only? No `else` or `&&`?

Comment: @LHCHIN you are free to use `if` `else` `else if` as well

Comment: @ScaryWombat i know, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are! Only `if` and `else` are used.

```
if (n1 >= n2) {
    if (n1 >= n3) {
        if (n2 >= n3) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n1, n2, n3);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n1, n3, n2);
        }
    } else {
        if (n2 >= n3) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n2, n3, n1);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n3, n1, n2);
        }
    }
} else {
    if (n1 >= n3) {
        if (n2 >= n3) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n2, n1, n3);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n3, n2, n1);
        }
    } else {
        if (n2 >= n3) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n2, n3, n1);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", n3, n2, n1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in many ways. My first attempt is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three number");
        int n1 = sc.nextInt();
        int n2 = sc.nextInt();
        int n3 = sc.nextInt();
        int max = 0, min = 0, med = 0;
        if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3) {
            max = n1;
            if (n2 > n3) {
                min = n3;
                med = n2;
            } else {
                min = n2;
                med = n3;
            }
        } else if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3) {
            max = n2;
            if (n1 > n3) {
                min = n3;
                med = n1;
            } else {
                min = n1;
                med = n3;
            }
        } else if (n3 > n1 && n3 > n2) {
            max = n3;
            if (n2 > n1) {
                min = n1;
                med = n2;
            } else {
                min = n2;
                med = n1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max + " " + med + " " + min);
    }
}
```

If you observe carefully inner if-else is repeating with different numbers. So could be extracted to a method returning min-max pair.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three number");
        int n1 = sc.nextInt();
        int n2 = sc.nextInt();
        int n3 = sc.nextInt();
        int max = 0, min = 0, med = 0;
        if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3) {
            max = n1;
            MinMaxPair minMaxPair = getMinMaxPair(n2, n3);
            min = minMaxPair.getMin();
            med = minMaxPair.getMax();
        } else if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3) {
            max = n2;
            MinMaxPair minMaxPair = getMinMaxPair(n1, n3);
            min = minMaxPair.getMin();
            med = minMaxPair.getMax();
        } else if (n3 > n1 && n3 > n2) {
            max = n3;
            MinMaxPair minMaxPair = getMinMaxPair(n1, n2);
            min = minMaxPair.getMin();
            med = minMaxPair.getMax();
        }
        System.out.println(max + " " + med + " " + min);
    }

    private static class MinMaxPair {
        private int min;
        private int max;

        public MinMaxPair(int n2, int n3) {
            this.min = n2;
            this.max = n3;
        }

        public int getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public int getMax() {
            return max;
        }
    }

    public static MinMaxPair getMinMaxPair(int n1, int n2) {
        if (n1 > n2) {
            return new MinMaxPair(n2, n1);
        } else {
            return new MinMaxPair(n1, n2);
        }
    }
}
```